# how to remove navigation bar bottom color iOS 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I create one application and in first page I add UINavigationController but I have one problem.
and it is bottom border in navigation bar....

I want remove this border bottom or clear color that's border.
please help me
[image]

Comment: my friend I want navigation bar wasn't image and was background color

Comment: @mamal10 read the accepted answer in the duplicate question. Setting the shadow image do a dummy `UIImage` does the trick.

Comment: my friend I tried it but not working

Comment: then include your attempt in the question and clearly specify why it does not work.

Comment: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true

Answer (score 2):

To remove bottom border from `UINavigationBar` you can use below method in app delegate:

```
- (void) removeBottomBarFromNav:(UINavigationBar *) navBar {
for (id subView in [navBar subviews]) {
    for (id subViewInner in [subView subviews])
    {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subView class]) isEqualToString:@"_UINavigationBarBackground"])
        {
            if ([subViewInner isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                [subViewInner removeFromSuperview];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

You can use this method as mention below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    home * ObjLoginPage = [[home alloc] initWithNibName:@"home" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ObjLoginPage];

    [self removeBottomBarFromNav:self.navigationController.navigationBar];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
}
```